# What does tag means in UiViewtableCell?

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I found the `tag` attribute in `UITableViewCell` at http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/8-automatic-uitableview-paging

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (cell.tag == kLoadingCellTag) {
        _currentPage++;
        [self fetchBeers];
    }
}
```

But what does the `tag` mean ? I can not found the meaning at Doc https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 4):

`tag` is declared in `UIView` and as such inherited by `UITableViewCell`. It is used to identify `UIView`s and its descendants from code. You can also set the `tag` in the `storyboard` editor.

From the `UIView` Class reference:

**tag**
An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.

`@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag`

**Discussion**

The default value is 0. You can set the value of this tag and use that value to identify the view later.